# How to run FlashWindow in Linux?

Tags: c++, linux, qt, user-interface

I need to highlight a window in the taskbar when the process is finished.

I call `::FlashWindow((HWND)winId(), false);` in Windows.
How can I make the same in Linux?

`QApplication::alert(this);` does not work for me.
KDE Desktop 5.

---

This code does not work for me.

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    connect(ui->pushButton, SIGNAL(released()), this, SLOT(test()));
}

void MainWindow::test()
{
    QThread::msleep(5000);
    QApplication::alert(this);
}
```

---

But this one works.

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    QTimer *timer = new QTimer();

    QObject::connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(timer_alert()));
    timer->start(5000);
}

void MainWindow::timer_alert() {
    QApplication::alert(this);
}
```

What is the difference?

Comment: The Unity launcher entry API works for many desktops - but not for all. You can try it out: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Unity/LauncherAPI (you don't have to use the library, you can use the dbus interface)

Answer (score 0):

There is no general method to accomplish this, because it depends on the **desktop environment**.

There may not be a "taskbar" (or a panel) at all. In the past, there was a similar issue for browser makers, trying to support the *window.getAttention()* method.

Even blinking the title bar may not be so easy, since Qt does not have any control over the window decoration (borders and title), so you may need to implement this manually using Xlib.

If you want to obtain the same effect on all the target platforms, you may consider implementing a simple "blinking" effect (e.g. playing with the window **opacity**). Beware though that window opacity is supported on X11 only if you run a compositor.